# How to redirect old URL that hasn't any slug to new one which has a slug

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Friends, this is a complex problem for me. I have researched on this many times and at last have came to you (with hope that I will get the solution). We had products URLs like:

```
/product_info.php/products_id/75
```

As per SEO, I wanted keyword rich URL so, we added a slug in products.php file and modified the URL as:

```
/product_info.php/products_id/75/product-title
```

But its also not an ideal URL. I wanted this as:

```
domainname.com/products/product-title/75
```

Changes I made in .htaccess file is as follows-

```
RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]{2})/?$ product_info.php?products_id=$2=$1 [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/product_info.php/products_id/([0-9]{2})/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ http://www.livevaastu.com/products/$2/$1
```

Now problem is- our old URLs (which has no slugs) are indexed by Google. And I am not getting any idea how to redirect those old ones to new ones. Also there are many products pages so I couldn't redirect them one-by-one. You guys are genius. Can you help me any how. (without laughing on me). M not a developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't produce product_info.php?products_id=$2=$1  from your old URLs of /product_info.php/products_id/75 because they don't have the product title ("slug").

For one thing product_info.php?products_id=$2=$1 doesn't make any sense. Is that a typo? What are the key/value pairs in that query string?? This should look something like products_id=$1&product_title=$2 where each derived "value" from the mod_rewrite match gets assigned to a known "key", something you can use in $_GET or $_REQUEST to find the value.

**Edit to help with what I think you are trying to achieve here, based on discussion:**

If you want your old URLs to lead to the new "pretty" URLs, you will need to use PHP to do this. As mentioned, there simply is not adequate information in the URL to invent the product names. But you could pretty easily have something at the top of each page (i.e. in a header file) which looked to see if the "title" $_GET parameter is present or not (once you clean up the double-equal sign and replace it with proper key/value pairs). This might look something like:

```
<?php
if( !isset( $_GET['product_title'] ) ) {

   // Code here to look up $product_title from the $product_id, presumably in a DB

   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: /products/$product_title/$product_id");
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the message, Devin. Actually key pairs in 'products_id=$2=$1' contains slug and id. As I mentioned that I wanted the URL to be looked like- domainname.com/products/product-title/75 (for which I have added some lines in .htaccess file given above). But headache is- I can't redirect the old ones (without slugs) to these new Urls. Kindly update me if it's creating any confusion. Regards.

Comment: My confusion is that you have two equal signs in a row. There are not key/value pairs here. I would expect products_id=$1&product_title=$2 as that would actually have key/value pairs. And you don't need to redirect the old URLs to the new URLs. There would be no point in that. You need to redirect the old URLs to the new same place they used to redirect to -- the proper content.

Comment: Thanks Devin, great help. I shall check it and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Devin, Sorry for the too much delay and thanks a lot for your help. We have used key value in the codes and also got able to redirect each page with a URL with slug- (/product_info.php/products_id/75 to http://www.livevaastu.com/products/vaastu-solution-for-students/75). Hope there might no problem from Google side.